# Is there a way to wrap the function return value (object) in Python using move instead of copy semantics?

Tags: c++, move, boost-python

Is there a way to wrap a C++ function that returns an object (value not pointer or reference) using move semantics without copying the object?

Example:

I have a function that creates a large object A and returns it using its move constructor:

```
class A {
public:
  A( A&& );
};

A createA() 
{
  // creates A here
  return std::move(A);
}
```

In C++, I can avoid copying A by "moving" it out of the function.  Now, I need to wrap A and createA in Python using boost python.  As far as I can tell, when a function returns an object, boost python would automatically invokes A's copy constructor.  If I don't provide a copy constructor for A, compilation fails.  My question is whether there is way to "move" the object into Python world without copying.

Comment: Did you want it to a return a reference to the object?

Comment: Please give a concrete, specific example of what you're looking for.  FYI, in `return x`, Python **never** copies x.

Comment: Can you be more specific, please?  Also, posting your code would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

The following code should work

```
struct A
{
  A() = default;
  A(A&&) = default;
};

A createA()
{
  return {};
}

using bp = boost::python;


bp::class_<A, boost::noncopyable, std:: shared_ptr<A>> (
  "A", "noncopyable class A", bp::no_init);

bp::def(
  "createA",
  +[]()
  {
    return std::make_shared<A> (createA()); 
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be trying to return a value to a new function. For instance:

```
def get_three():
    value = 3
    return value

def square(x):
    square = x * x
    return square

print square(get_three())

>> 9
```

You don't have to set the value of get_three temporarily, like this:

```
three = get_three()
print square(three)
```

You can just pass the function straight in.